# Solving a system of vector equations

Tags: equation-solving

I had a problem where I had to solve a series of equations where some of the variables can take multiple value such as shown below

```
c[0]={0.0871817, 0.0850908, 0.0826321}

c[3]={0.0874968, 0.0857884, 0.0838024}

d[0]={2.23049*10^-6, 6.46928*10^-6, 0.0000128172}

d[1]={2.04172*10^-6, 5.90291*10^-6, 0.0000116484}

d[2]={1.86443*10^-6, 5.37164*10^-6, 0.0000105544}
```

And I'd like to solve for conc[1] and conc[2]

```
d[0]*(c[0] - conc[1]) = d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2])
d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2]) = d[2]*(conc[2] - c[3])
```

So I used Solve in such way

```
Solve[Thread[d[0]*(c[0] - conc[1]) == d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2])] &&
Thread[d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2]) == d[2]*(conc[2] - c[3])], {conc[1],
conc[2]}]
```

which didn't gave me the right answer. I wonder if this is a legit approach or there's any other way to do it? I had a similar question yesterday that prompt me to use Thread for this kind of problems https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97054/solve-equation-with-a-variable-of-multiple-value I'm not sure if this method fit for my current problem.

Thanks for reading and let me know if you have any questions or suggestions!

Comment: What kind of beasts are your `conc[ ]` supposed to be?Lists? Reals?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be a List with three values just like the other variables defined. Maybe I have to define those two to be Thread as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
conc[1] = Array[x, 3];
conc[2] = Array[y, 3];

Solve[d[0]*(c[0]    - conc[1]) == d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2]) &&
      d[1]*(conc[1] - conc[2]) == d[2]*(conc[2] - c[3]), 
      Flatten[{conc[1], conc[2]}]]

(*
 {{x[1] -> 0.0872775, x[2] -> 0.0853022, x[3] -> 0.0829852, 
   y[1] -> 0.0873822, y[2] -> 0.0855338, y[3] -> 0.0833736}}
*)
```

Comment: How could I get the value from $x[1]$,..$y[3]$?  these just return themselves expression.

Answer (score 1):

Because `d[1] (conc[1] - conc[2])` makes up one side of both equations, it can be eliminated, and the system is shown to be under-determined. Therefore, it has infinitely many solution sets. Belisarius's answer gives one of them, but I know no reason why it should be preferred.

Here is the general solution.

```
uu = Array[u, 3]; vv = Array[v, 3];
Solve[d[0] (c[0] - uu) == d[2] (vv - c[3]), Flatten @ {uu, vv}]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>
> ```
> {v[1] -> 0.191796 - 1.19634 u[1], 
>  v[2] -> 0.188267 - 1.20434 u[2], 
>  v[3] -> 0.18415 - 1.21439 u[3]}
> ```

We can generate any specific solution with

```
sol[usol_] := Join[usol, gensol /. usol]
```

For example,

```
sol[{u[1] -> 0., u[2] -> 0., u[3] -> 0.}]
```

> ```
> {u[1] -> 0., u[2] -> 0., u[3] -> 0., 
>  v[1] -> 0.191796,  v[2] -> 0.188267, v[3] -> 0.18415}
> ```

or

```
sol[{u[1] -> 0.08727751016208445, 
     u[2] -> 0.08530217552915369, 
     u[3] -> 0.08298516000872024}]
```

> ```
> {u[1] -> 0.0872775, u[2] -> 0.0853022, u[3] -> 0.0829852, 
>  v[1] -> 0.0873822, v[2] -> 0.0855338, v[3] -> 0.0833736}
> ```

which is belisarius' solution.

Comment: The reason that this equation is under-determined is because I slightly changed my original code where the second equation is d[nodes - 2]*(conc[nodes - 2] - conc[nodes - 1]) ==  d[nodes - 1]*(conc[nodes - 1] - c[nodes])  plus an array function And @@ Array[ d[#]*(conc[#] - conc[# + 1]) == d[# + 1]*(conc[# + 1] - conc[# + 2]) &, nodes - 3, 1]  I guess the answer I'm looking for is more like how to define a multi-value variable which belisarius suggested using the Array function. I might've overlooked the actual solution to my question. Thanks for pointing that out.